# how to add posts with image programmatically in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

This the code to add a post programmatically in wordpress

```
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');

global $user_ID;

$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => 'Table Tennis',
    'post_content' => 'Table tennis or ping-pong is a sport in which two or four players hit a lightweight ball back and forth using a table tennis racket. The game takes place on a hard table divided by a net. Except for the initial serve, players must allow a ball played toward them only one bounce on their side of the table and must return it so that it bounces on the opposite side. Points are scored when a player fails to return the ball within the rules.',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => $user_ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_category' => array(2),
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

how to add image to the post?

i am new to wordpress,thanks in advance..

Comment: did you mean Post Thumbnails? if you, would the following link help: [https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)...?

Answer (score 0):

This will upload the file using WordPress and then insert it on the post as a featured image.

```
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null);
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => $filename,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $thumbnail, $post_id );
// you must first include the image.php file
// for the function wp_generate_attachment_metadata() to work
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $thumbnail );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

// add featured image to post
add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
```